# Аппаратный RAID1 на SSD

Tags: ssd, raid

Есть в наличии такая материнская плата:

```
> wmic baseboard get manufacturer
Manufacturer
Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.

> wmic baseboard get product
Product
F2A68HM-S1
```

И пока в выборе пары SSD из следующих:

https://www.e-katalog.ru/SAMSUNG-MZ-76E1T0BW.htm
https://www.e-katalog.ru/SAMSUNG-MZ-7LH960NE.htm
https://www.e-katalog.ru/SAMSUNG-MZ-76Q1T0BW.htm
https://www.e-katalog.ru/KINGSTON-SUV500-960G.htm

И вот у меня возникла куча вопросов по настройке и целесообразности всего этого...

Стоит задача хранить на этом рейде базу 1С (база хранится через MS SQL 2017).

1) Какую пару SSD лучше выбрать?
2) Что будет ели сломается материнская плата?
3) Как проводить диагностику отдельных накопителей в этом рейде, для выявления претендентов на замену?
4) Что будет если один диск сломается?
5) И какие еще потенциально могут возникнуть проблемы?
-----
6) Что если придется подключить один диск из этого рейда, как обычный диск? с него информация будет считываться исправно?

Comment: 2) плохо. 3) как обычно, смарт 4) очень плохо 5) не заработает

Comment: @KoVadim а чуть подробнее? почему и как? тогда может вообще не стоит такое затевать?

Comment: 4 - тут очевидно - у Вас остается половина данных. И если бекапа нет, то будет только половина данных, но кусками. 2 - Вам придется искать такой же raid контроллер. Просто взять любой \вряд ли просто получится. Если бюджет такой, то я бы лучше взял nvme и скорость будет в 3-4 раза быстрее, и проще в настройка

Comment: @KoVadim "у Вас остается половина данных" разве RAID1 это не полное зеркалирование данных? RAID0 это деление данных по дискам для увеличения скорости? или я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: не, это я спутал raid0 (stripped) с raid 0.